# iOS In App Purchase - Buying more than one, of the same, non-consumable item

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Is there a way that I can purchase a non-consumable item more than once?

Right now I purchase it but I cannot purchase it more than once. All I am adding is the ability to purchase a "slot" once the user needs it. The slot just holds more information but is not needed in the app.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: If it should be bought more than once, then it's consumable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is actually a programming question, the answer is no. A non-consumable can only be purchased once. And this is across the user's devices too.

To allow a user to purchase something more than once you need to use a consumable product.

Comment: That is what I thought - I just want the customer to keep what they purchased. Thanks!